# How could I read a file with header and then save the final file with header again?

Tags: python

I'd like to read file1 with given header and then implement some mathematical operations on , for example, the x and Imag columns. Finally I want to save the final file with header again.

How could I do it?

```
File1:
    #ID     ra      dec     x       y       Umag    Bmag    Vmag    Rmag    Imag
    1.0   53.141 -27.7967 3491.37 4060.43 23.1612 23.7058 23.0223 22.5351 22.1785
    2.0   53.140 -27.7956 3496.66 4076.57 24.1362 24.8441 25.0093 24.7304 24.5864
    3.0   53.142 -27.8008 3471.25 3997.29 24.1729 25.3841 25.3501 25.1032 25.0042
    4.0   53.138 -27.7891 3527.16 4175.46 24.4685 26.1972 26.1785 25.5567 25.3188 
    5.0   53.146 -27.8085 3424.83 3880.66 24.425  25.1966 25.2755 24.9514 24.3456
```

Comment: How do you read the file?

Comment: I usually read my files with read_array from scipy.io or genfromtxt commands.

Comment: Could you post some sample code?

Answer (score 1):

Use the python csv reader - with space as a delimiter, it can handle header rows fine, write the new file with the same.